# jquery modal dialog is laughing at me - dialog shows up modeless

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I got stuck trying to show a simple jquery modal dialog. The dialog is shown but in a modeless way.

I have read other posts and checked:

- There is a link to jquery-ui.css
- I've included modal:true parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="userPanelDlg">
    <div class="input -clearfix">
        <p>User</p>
        <input name="username" type="text">
        <p>Pass</p>
        <input name="password" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#userPanelDlg").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am referencing jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery UI 1.9.2, with jquery.ui.css as an external resource - and it works for me with your code: [**CLICK HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/urbz/w7ef714j/)

Comment: Do you have any other jQuery elements in your code? Maybe you're missing some references cause like urbz said it worked for me as well.

Comment: The code is executed into $(window).load(function() {});

Comment: I found the problem. I misunderstood a basic javascript concept. The dialog IS shown as modal but the execution follows after dialog() call. I thought that, as in other languages like java, dialog({modal:true}) was a blocking call (like dialog.setVisible(true) in java). Thx for your help anyway

Comment: @acimutal set this as answered question because is currently showing as unanswared. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I misunderstood a basic javascript concept. The dialog IS shown as modal but the execution follows after dialog() call. I thought that, as in other languages like java, dialog({modal:true}) was a blocking call (like dialog.setVisible(true) in java). Thx for your help anyway